# django KeyError: 'some-ForeignKey-field-in-model'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-orm

I am very badly stuck on this error for days, and I am unable to understand what it is trying to tell me as it is only 2 words.

The error is coming when I am trying to insert data into the DB table using python manage.py shell

```
> from app_name.models import Usermanagement
> from app_name.models import Inquery

i = Inquery( inqueryid=6, inquerynumber="INQ765758499", sourceairportid=Airport(airportid=1), 
destinationairportid=Airport(airportid=21),  stageid=Stage(stageid=1), commoditytypeid=6, customerid=Customer(customerid=1),
branchid=1, transactiontype="AGENT", businesstype="Self", hodate="2020-11-18",  totalshipmentunits=56, 
unitid=100, grossweight=100, volumemetricweight=100, remark="test", 
dateofcreation="2018-11-20 00:00:00", dateofmodification="2018-11-20 00:00:00", 
createdby = Usermanagement(userid=0), modifiedby = Usermanagement(userid=0))
```

#error

```
KeyError: 'createdby'
```

#traceback

```
File C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py:768, in Model.save(self, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
    757 def save(
    758     self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None
    759 ):
    760     """
    761     Save the current instance. Override this in a subclass if you want to
    762     control the saving process.
   (...)
    766     non-SQL backends), respectively. Normally, they should not be set.
    767     """
--> 768     self._prepare_related_fields_for_save(operation_name="save")
    770     using = using or router.db_for_write(self.__class__, instance=self)
    771     if force_insert and (force_update or update_fields):

File C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py:1092, in Model._prepare_related_fields_for_save(self, operation_name, fields)
   1087         # If the relationship's pk/to_field was changed, clear the
   1088         # cached relationship.
   1089         if getattr(obj, field.target_field.attname) != getattr(
   1090             self, field.attname
   1091         ):
-> 1092             field.delete_cached_value(self)
   1093 # GenericForeignKeys are private.
   1094 for field in self._meta.private_fields:

File C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\mixins.py:28, in FieldCacheMixin.delete_cached_value(self, instance)
     27 def delete_cached_value(self, instance):
---> 28     del instance._state.fields_cache[self.get_cache_name()]

KeyError: 'createdby'
```

#models.py (only some part of it, for sort Question)

```
# this model is in freight app
class Inquery(models.Model):
    
    inqueryid = models.BigAutoField(db_column='InqueryID', primary_key=True)
    inquerynumber = models.CharField(db_column='InqueryNumber', max_length=45)
    sourceairportid = models.ForeignKey(Airport, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='SourceAirportID',related_name="Flight_inquery_source")
    destinationairportid = models.ForeignKey(Airport, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='DestinationAirportID',related_name="Flight_inquery_destination")
    stageid = models.ForeignKey('Stage', on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='StageID')
    commoditytypeid = models.IntegerField(db_column='CommodityTypeID')
    customerid = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='CustomerID')
    branchid = models.IntegerField(db_column='BranchID')
    transactiontype = models.CharField(db_column='TransactionType', max_length=10)
    businesstype = models.CharField(db_column='BusinessType', max_length=15)
    hodate = models.DateTimeField(db_column='HODate')
    totalshipmentunits = models.CharField(db_column='TotalShipmentUnits', max_length=20)
    unitid = models.CharField(db_column='UnitID', max_length=3)
    grossweight = models.FloatField(db_column='GrossWeight')
    volumemetricweight = models.FloatField(db_column='VolumemetricWeight')
    remark = models.CharField(db_column='Remark', max_length=8000)
    dateofcreation = models.DateTimeField(db_column='DateOfCreation')
    dateofmodification = models.DateTimeField(db_column='DateOfModification')
    createdby = models.ForeignKey('accounts.Usermanagement', on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='CreatedBy', to_field='createdby',related_name="Usermanagement_Inquery_createdby")
    modifiedby = models.ForeignKey('accounts.Usermanagement', on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='ModifiedBy', to_field='modifiedby',related_name="Usermanagement_Inquery_modifiedby")
    isactive = models.IntegerField(db_column='IsActive')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.inquerynumber

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Inquery'
```

#another app model

```
class Usermanagement(AbstractBaseUser):
    userid = models.BigAutoField(db_column='UserID', primary_key=True)
    emailid = models.CharField(db_column='EmailID', unique=True, max_length=45)
    roleid = models.ForeignKey(Role, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='RoleID')
    organizationid = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='OrganizationID')
    firstname = models.CharField(db_column='FirstName', max_length=45)
    middlename = models.CharField(db_column='MiddleName', max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    lastname = models.CharField(db_column='LastName', max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    numberofretry = models.IntegerField(db_column='NumberOfRetry',default=0)
    timeoffset = models.CharField(db_column='TimeOffSet', max_length=6,default="+5:30")
    password = models.CharField(db_column='Password', max_length=45)
    passwordexpirydate = models.DateTimeField(db_column='PasswordExpiryDate',default='2022-12-30 12:30:59')
    dateofcreation = models.DateTimeField(db_column='DateOfCreation',auto_now_add = True)
    dateofmodification = models.DateTimeField(db_column='DateOfModification',auto_now = True)
    createdby = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='CreatedBy',unique=True) #this field is FK in many other models
    modifiedby = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='ModifiedBy',unique=True) #this field is FK in many other models
    isactive = models.BooleanField(db_column='IsActive',default=1)

    last_login = False

    objects = UsermanagementCustomUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = "emailid"
    EMAIL_FIELD = "emailid"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["roleid","organizationid","firstname","passwordexpirydate","createdby","modifiedby"]


    def __str__(self):
        return self.emailid
--------------------- some more code ------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use `Usermanagement.objects.get(userid=0)` instead of `Usermanagement(userid=0)`
To get an existing foreignkey and not create an instance of a User not saved in the database and thus not reachable

Comment: Thanks bro,..........It worked...Thanks a lot.....not my query looks like...

Comment: Inquery ( inqueryid=6, inquerynumber="INQ765758499", sourceairportid=Airport(airportid=1), destinationairportid=Airport(airportid=21), stageid=Stage(stageid=1), commoditytypeid=6, customerid=Customer(customerid=1), branchid=1, transactiontype="AGENT", businesstype="Self", hodate="2020-11-18", totalshipmentunits=56,unitid=100, grossweight=100, volumemetricweight=100,remark="test", dateofcreation="2018-11-20 00:00:00",  dateofmodification="2018-11-20 00:00:00", createdby = Usermanagement.objects.get(userid=0), modifiedby = Usermanagement.objects.get(userid=0), isactive=1)

Answer (score 0):

as answered by @vctrd

my query now is :
Inquery ( inqueryid=6, inquerynumber="INQ765758499", sourceairportid=Airport(airportid=1), destinationairportid=Airport(airportid=21), stageid=Stage(stageid=1), commoditytypeid=6, customerid=Customer(customerid=1), branchid=1, transactiontype="AGENT", businesstype="Self", hodate="2020-11-18", totalshipmentunits=56,unitid=100, grossweight=100, volumemetricweight=100,remark="test", dateofcreation="2018-11-20 00:00:00",  dateofmodification="2018-11-20 00:00:00", createdby = Usermanagement.objects.get(userid=0), modifiedby = Usermanagement.objects.get(userid=0), isactive=1)

Comment: @Chris there was an option provided my the stackoverflow as "Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style" and thats what I did . Other than that I have upvoted the "vctrd" answer but my reputation for now is less then 15 so this is the message shown to me "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."

Comment: [Self-answers are fine](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), but they're meant for when you are actually providing your own answer. In this case, vctrd answered your question. You read their answer, decided that it worked, and then posted your own answer saying as much. You are not obligated to [accept answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/248627) that answer your question, but that is the correct way to indicate that your question has been answered by a particular answer. You can do that on any question you ask, no matter how much reputation you have, via the ✔️ (not ⬆).